# Запуск программ на управляющей машине через Ansible

Tags: python, ansible, devops

Можно ли запустить через ansible какую-либо программу или скрипт на управляющей машине, с которой производится управление списком hosts ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900236/run-command-on-the-ansible-host

Comment: ответ был дан уже по предыдущему вопросу: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900236/run-command-on-the-ansible-host

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: a play that runs entirely on the ansible host
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - name: check out a git repository
    git: repo=git://foosball.example.org/path/to/repo.git dest=/local/path
```